# ubuntu bash script with postgres9.4: shp2pgsql unable to open tiger line shape file

Tags: bash, postgresql, ubuntu, shapefile

```
DIRECTORY="/home/charm/Documents/tiger_files/"
cd $DIRECTORY

for f in *.shp;
do
    FILENAME="$(basename -s .shp "$f")"
    shp2pgsql -I -s 4269 $DIRECTORY $f ${FILENAME} > ${FILENAME}.sql
done
```

`f` grabs all the files in the tiger_files directory that end with .shp.

`FILENAME` = the basename of the .shp file for naming a new table and creating a sql script.

shp2pgsql is installed. You can access it from the command line.

shp2pgsql is sitting at **usr/bin/shp2pgsql.**

The loop is successful and creates an empty sql script - why is shp2pgsql not getting accessed?

The console says: Unable to open /directory/.shp or /directory/.SHP. /directory/:dbf file (.dbf) can not be opened.

Comment: Simplest of solutions:  Concatenation!

Comment: smash $DIRECTORY and $f together.  No space. $DIRECTORY$f  = now it works like a charm!

Comment: You should use double quotes around any variable which contains a file name, though.